# Teams Room - Not showing upcoming meetings

Tags: microsoft-teams

I'm setting up the Logitech TAP for the first time and seem to have run into an issue. We run Exchange Hybrid and Teams only (our SfB on-prem server was decommissioned recently) - I was able to follow the instructions from the [MS Docs site](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/rooms/with-exchange-online), and skipped the Powershell commands for SfB.

I can log in using the meeting room credentials, and I can make and receive calls - the only thing I can't see are the upcoming meetings that I created for today. Has anybody seen this issue before?

Comment: We are investigating this internally, will soon update you with resolution.

Comment: Thanks @Manish-MSFT - is there an update?

Comment: We are trying to repro this at our end.

Comment: We tried to repro this but couldn't since, this issue is more on deployment side it must be redirected to product channel, please reach out to the [Product support channels](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/feedback#product-support-channels) for Microsoft Teams.